# Extend a columns value in same table

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kustomize, kusto-explorer

I have the below datatable, where WId and ParentId are values of the same column but are related to each other. The State that's shown here is for WId, I want to extend another column as ParentIdState which should be the State of ParentId. (The value of State also exists in the same table). How can I do so?

```
datatable(WId:int, WType:string, Link:string, ParentId:dynamic, State:string)
[
    374075, "Deliverable", "Link", dynamic(315968), "Started", 
]
```

Updating further for clarification -

```
datatable(WId:int, WType:string, Link:string, ParentId:dynamic, State:string)
[
    374075, "Deliverable", "Link", dynamic(315968), "Started", 
    315968, "Parent", "Link", dynamic(467145), "Planned"
]
```

ParentId is dynamic because it's extracted from a JSON. In the above datatable ParentId is actually a value of WId and has its relevant details. My intent is to extend my table to give ParentState in another column like below -

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7vax.png)

Comment: Looks like the join operator is what you're looking for: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer

Comment: Why `ParentId` is of type `dynamic`?

Comment: It's extracted from JSON.

Comment: I've read the updated question, but I still don't understand what you're trying to do. Please update the question to provide a minimal dataset (using [datatable format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datatableoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer)), the expected output, and an explanation, and we'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator) or [`lookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/lookupoperator).

Comment: I have updated my ask, if it helps clarifying further. Unsure if lookup would help.

Comment: I've read the updated question, but I still don't understand what you're trying to do. Please update the question to provide a minimal dataset (using [datatable format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datatableoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer)), the expected output, and an explanation, and we'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could `join` 2 tables:

1. the one you provided with a small modification - type of `ParentId` is changed from `dynamic` to `int` (the same as the type of `WId` as the join will be performed on it).
2. a simplified version of table 1) - with only 2 columns: `WId` and `State`

```
let data = datatable(WId:int, WType:string, Link:string, ParentId:dynamic, State:string)
[
    374075, "Deliverable", "Link", dynamic(315968), "Started", 
    315968, "Parent", "Link", dynamic(467145), "Planned"
]
| extend ParentId = toint(ParentId); // to make sure the type of ParentId is the same as WId

data
| join kind=leftouter (data | project WId, State) on $left.ParentId == $right.WId
| project WId, WType, Link, ParentId, State, ParentState = State1
```

There might be some optimization to be done here (for example by using [materialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/materializefunction), but I'm not entirely sure)

You can also achieve the same with `lookup`

```
data
| lookup (data | project WId, State) on $left.ParentId == $right.WId
| project WId, WType, Link, ParentId, State, ParentState = State1
```